# Creating Php Multi User Login

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a database with 2 tables, table1 stores only id, username and password, while table2 stores id, username, date, and other information.
My question now is how can i set my codes in such a way that each time user A logs in, and click on "view profile" he or she can only see there own profile based on there username and not other peoples profile. the same goes to user B, user C and user D and so on.

My code for the log is:

```
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)

{
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db("uloaku") or die("cannot find data base!");
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM keyaku WHERE    username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."' AND   password='".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows!=0)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
}
    if ($username==$dbusername&&$password=$dbpassword)
{
    echo "Welcome $username";
}
else
    echo "Invalid Password";
}
else
die("Invalid User");

}

else
 die("Please Enter a UserName and Password.");

?>
```

My code to view profile is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("uloaku", $con);
$count = 1;

$y = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE id=24");
if(mysql_num_rows($y) != 0){

echo "<table border=\"1\" width=\"800\" >";
echo "<tr id=\"bold\">
<td>No</td>
<td align=\"center\" width=\"120\">Account Owner</td>
<td align=\"center\" width=\"120\">Deposit Date</td>
<td align=\"center\" id=\"bold\" width=\"120\">Current Balance</td>
<td align=\"center\" id=\"bold\" width=\"90\">Intrest</td>
<td align=\"center\" width=\"150\">Available Balance</td>
<td align=\"center\">Account Status</td>
</tr>";

while ($z = mysql_fetch_array($y, MYSQL_BOTH)){
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$count++."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[1]."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[2]."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[3]."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[4]."</td>
        <td id=\"color\" align=\"center\">".$z[5]."</td>
        <td id=\"color3\" align=\"left\">".$z[6]."</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

Hope someone can help me out, will really appreciat it if a full code is given for example or correction so other people that have similar problem can refer and make corrections. Thanks

Comment: Hi jOK, whats the edited part of the code? mind to share so i can take note of it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) for this. Start every script in which the information is needed with `session_start()`. After that you can use the superglobal `$_SESSION` as an array (very much like `$_POST`). The contents of the `$_SESSION`-array are saved between requests.

So what you can do is:

- Put `session_start()` at the top of all your scripts
- When a user logs in, save their id in the `$_SESSION` array (like; `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = $row['userid']`);
- In consequent pages you can use `$_SESSION['logged_in']` to get the id of the user that called the login script.

Comment: I have been doing it this way for a long time and is really the best way to do it, only thing i can add is when a user logs out remember to unset your session. by using: unset($_SESSION['user_id']);

Comment: Or, if you have more fields that need to be unset you can use `session_destroy();` to, well, destroy the session.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to adjust the following line:

```
if ($username==$dbusername&&$password=$dbpassword)
```

to

```
if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
```

However that test is superfluous.

By sending the request to mysql, if you get a line back, then you had a match, you dont need to fetch the rows, or, values, as you arent using them. You got a valid login when you found

```
if ($numrows!=0)
```